# Scheme for Common NGINX Configuration Across Multiple Servers

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

My setup consists of several servers including production, production fail-over, developer instances, etc. The production and production fail-over servers periodically swap roles. I would like all of the servers to have consistent environments. I accomplish this in Apache by using virtual hosts, and enabling/disabling them as necessary.

An issue that I've run into is that the NGINX main configuration file has settings that are tuned to the server hardware, particularly the `events` context. I'm currently leaning towards having an `events-[subdomain].conf` file for each server and creating a symbolic link to it named `events.conf`. I could use the appropriate file merely by changing the symbolic link.

```
events {
    include events.conf;
}
```

Is this a good way to handle it? Downsides? Better solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes, but there might be a slightly better way.

***EDIT** The convention described in the paragraph below is now deprecated, and any additional configuration files should be referenced in the main configuration file using the [`include`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) directive*

Longer answer: ~In Nginx each server or website is typically defined in an external file, often in the "enabled-sites" or "sites-enabled" subdirectory of the nginx configuration directory - I called mine enabled-sites as it makes changing to it quicker with tab completion.  The main Nginx configuration file typically includes everything in this directory.

You could put all configuration files for all servers into this subdirectory and synchronise the directory, or refer to a directory in a shared location. The nginx.conf for each server could include only the files required by that server at that time. This would be reasonably quick to change.

However, automation is good. If you can define your configuration files so they work on all servers in that role you may be able to avoid manual changes, and it might work better behind a load balancer. The nginx.conf might be different but the server configs the same. This should be pretty easy.

Comment: Can you please provide a source that explains who decided and why they decided this method is "deprecated"?

Comment: This is a five year old post. @ppicom edited the post recently to say that this method is deprecated. I have noticed that in my newer Nginx servers you don't edit the main nginx.conf, you edit a file that's included or include your own file.

Comment: Sure thing @Paul, no problem! This comes in the [NGINX cookbook](https://www.nginx.com/resources/library/complete-nginx-cookbook/), page 5:

"The _etc/nginx/conf.d_ directory contains the default HTTP server configuration files. [ ... ] It's best practice to utilise _include_  statements [ ... ] In some packages this folder is called _sites-enabled_, and configuration files are linked from a folder named _sites-available_; this convention is deprecated."

Comment: @perepm Thank you. I just learned a user that did an edit can be pinged! I actually think your edit should be a new answer instead of an edit, but I haven't taken the time to review Meta, as I'm sure this has been addressed before.

Comment: The answers to questions are point in time, they're not maintained. A comment on the answer that it may not be current best practice sounds fine, but even that is unnecessary really. If we wanted to keep every question / answer on Stack Exchange current it would be a massive undertaking.

Comment: @Paul I'm glad I could help :) I've read the question in more detail and I don't think my input on the subject it's good enough to be an answer. I don't address how to "dynamically" switch between backends. Although defining upstreams and changing them as OP sees fit might be a solution.

Comment: @Tim I agree that keeping every answer on point it's an asymptotic goal. But given the value that the StackExchange delivers, I believe it's worth approaching it as much as possible :D

Comment: I disagree - answers are point in time. If someone updates them, sure, but I'm not going to maintain the 1200 odd answers I've provided - that would be near a full time job.